# Can't run ELF 32-bit on x86_x64 server even after adding i386

Tags: 64-bit, steam, 32-bit

I'm trying to run a 32 bit app on a 64 bit server. Here are the steps I followed to make that work:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libc6:i386 libncurses5:i386 libstdc++6:i386
```

And even after that i get the following:

```
./steamcmd.sh: line 29: /home/steam/steamcmd/linux32/steamcmd: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
```

Some info :

```
uname -i
```

give me:

```
x86_64
```

And 
    file linux32/steamcmd
gives me:

```
linux32/steamcmd: ELF 32-bit LSB  executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.34, BuildID[sha1]=17188c02dec11be2af104afd625f39a2c89b54c7, not stripped
```

Comment: So when you run ldd on the executable, what libraries are listed as "not found"?

Comment: the command gives me this : 
        not a dynamic executable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing the 32 bit loader, which causes ldd to falsely claim the "not a dynamic executable", instead of the correct "wrong architecture" error.  The 32 bit ld is in package libc6-i386.  I'll file the bug on the ldd report, never got around to file it.

Comment: thx i ended up installing a newer version of ubuntu but still good to know what was what